# Disable or update Apple ID settings, or click "Not Now" on simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane

I am developing a react native application, and using ios UI Tests and fastlane to take screenshots of the app. The issue is that the simulator keeps wanting me to update my apple ID settings and it's blocking the automated tests from running. Is there a way to turn these off so that I don't need to update, or if not, a way to wait until it pops up and click "Not Now"?

[image]

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
setupSnapshot(app)
app.launch()
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual it was a case of not knowing what to Google. Finally tried "disable system popups ui tests" and found this article which was helpful:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/handling-system-alerts-in-ui-tests/